# Kafka Connect distributed mode- error forwarding REST request

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect (SpoolDir connector) in distributed mode. After starting the worker, when I send a rest api request, a response with an EOFException is received.
I checked that the connector is working fine in standalone mode.

Http Response:

```
{"error_code":500,"message":"IO Error trying to forward REST request:
java.io.EOFException: HttpConnectionOverHTTP@7801635a::SocketChannelEndPoint@45ad3c42{broker/168.183.37.116:8083<->/10.96.134.132:65453,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=522046/0}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}
>HttpConnectionOverHTTP@7801635a(l:/10.96.134.132:65453 <-> r:broker/168.183.37.116:8083,closed=false)=>HttpChannelOverHTTP@2991a896(exchange=HttpExchange@45b72f1c req=TERMINATED/null@null res=PENDING/null@null
[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@1b783029(req=QUEUED,snd=COMPLETED,failure=null[HttpGenerator@379b5028{s=START}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@13ea8b55(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1}]]"}
```

The server logs show the following error:

```
 ERROR IO error forwarding REST request:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient:143)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.EOFException: HttpConnectionOverHTTP@7801635a::SocketChannelEndPoint@45ad3c42{broker/168.183.37.116:8083<->/10.96.134.132:65453,ISHUT,fill=-,flush=-,to=522046/0}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnectionOverHTTP@7801635a(l:/10.96.134.132:65453 <-> r:broker/168.183.37.116:8083,closed=false)=>HttpChannelOverHTTP@2991a896(exchange=HttpExchange@45b72f1c req=TERMINATED/null@null res=PENDING/null@null)[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@1b783029(req=QUEUED,snd=COMPLETED,failure=null)[HttpGenerator@379b5028{s=START}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@13ea8b55(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=CLOSED,0 of -1}]]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:711)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:125)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestClient.httpRequest(RestClient.java:65)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.completeOrForwardRequest(ConnectorsResource.java:369)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource.createConnector(ConnectorsResource.java:164)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        ...
```

Following is the properties file:

```
bootstrap.servers=kaas-test:443
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=<truststore-location>
ssl.truststore.password=<truststore-password>
ssl.keystore.location=<keystore-location>
ssl.keystore.password=<keystore-password>
ssl.key.password=<key-password>

producer.security.protocol=SSL
producer.ssl.truststore.location=<truststore-location>
producer.ssl.keystore.location=<keystore-location>
producer.ssl.truststore.password=<truststore-password>
producer.ssl.keystore.password=<keystore-password>
producer.ssl.key.password=<key-password>

group.id=tenant

schema.generation.enabled=true
schema.generation.value.name=schemavalue
schema.generation.key.name=schemakey

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=3

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=3

status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=3

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

rest.port=28082
rest.hostname=localhost

plugin.path=connect-jars/confluentinc-connect-transforms-1.3.2/,connect-jars/jcustenborder-kafka-connect-spooldir-2.0.46/
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm creating a single worker only. Added the properties file in the question.

Comment: What if you change `rest.hostname` to use the external hostname of the server?

Comment: Also, `rest.listeners`, I think is the preferred Connect property

Comment: Are there other connect clusters at all? You have two IPs in your error... `l:/10.96.134.132:65453 <-> r:broker/168.183.37.116:8083`

Comment: @OneCricketeer what is the external hostname of a server? Will it be the same name which is written against the `bootstrap-servers` field?

Comment: No, I have been trying to start only one worker. But i changed the port number several times while trying to resolve the error. Can this be the reason for the two IPs? I assumed that these two are the IP addresses between whom the connection is made.

Comment: You can use `hostname -f` to find it, but if you're only using one connect server, I'm not sure that's going to matter. You could also try removing the rest settings, the producer security protocol (don't you need to add consumer security protocol?), then try changing the group id. I also don't recognize those schema generation settings for the worker configuration+StringConverter doesn't have schemas, so you should remove those too

Comment: @OneCricketeer From what I read, producer security protocol is required since this is a source connector (consumer for sink). Anyhow, i tried removing these configurations along with the `rest.hostname`. But it is still the same. Could you please explain which property should i change (reference to StringConverter mentioned by you)

Comment: Also, when I tried to run the connector using docker (with the same configurations, plus one property for rest.advertised.host.name), it was working fine.

Comment: @OneCricketeer is there anything else which I could try changing to make it work?

Comment: Are you using the same version in Docker? What if you exec into the container and copy out the property file and use that?